# Azure Express route ip prefix

Tags: azure, vpn, express-router

Expressroute in Azure Is there a way to use a public IP address instead of a private one for Nat? If so, what was the ip prefix standard we can use is there anything specific ?

for example /29 /30 iprefix suggestions?
Express route NAT using public ip

Answer (score 0):

In Azure ExpressRoute, you can use a public IP address instead of a private one for NAT.

Using public Ip address of NAT you must use a unique `/29` subnet or two `/30` subnets. The specific IP prefix that you choose will depend on your specific requirements and the size of your virtual network.

[image]

***Note***: NAT Gateway supports a maximum of 16 IP addresses. the quota for prefix addresses `17` exceeds limit of `16`

You can choose /29 or/30 Ip prefix like below:

[image]

Check the [MsDoc](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/expressroute/expressroute-routing#public-ip-address-requirement) ExpressRoute routing requirements.

Ensure that in your virtual network subnet Nat gateway is associated like below:

[image]

References:

[Manage a public IP address with a NAT gateway - Azure Virtual Network | Microsoft Learn](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/virtual-network/ip-services/configure-public-ip-nat-gateway)

[Azure ExpressRoute: NAT requirements for circuits | Microsoft Learn](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/expressroute/expressroute-nat)